# Is there any way to fetch table record data from sql server to web form from another form?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, asp.net-web-api

I have two Web forms. One is LoginForm and Second is StudentStatus Form by Login with id and password in LoginForm i want to show Student Status record from StatusTable in StudentStatus Form...
Is there any way to fetch data from squal server from one form to another?
This is my LoginForm Code...

```cs
 





protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = "Data Source = SAAD_EBAD\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Custom Test; Trusted_Connection = Yes";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            string _sqlQuery = "Select count(*) from Student_Status where User_Name='" + Usertxt.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sqlQuery, con);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            con.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                con.Open();
                string _checkPasswordQuery = "Select Student_Password From Student_Status Where User_Name='" + Usertxt.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_checkPasswordQuery, con);
                string _password = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");

                **if (_password == PasswordTxt.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = Usertxt.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("~/Student Status.aspx");
                    if (_password.Equals(PasswordTxt.Text))
                    {
                        Student_Status.CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType(,"select Student_Degree_Status from Student_Status" );
                    }**

                }
                else
                {

                    string str = "Sorry,Password is not correct";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" + str + "');", true);

                }
            }
            else
            {

                string str2 = "User Name is not correct";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" + str2 + "');", true);
            }

           
        }
```

The code in bold (quoted) form i am having concern and issue it is not working. ihust want to show data from sql server from one form to another by login

Comment: I don't know, but your code has other issues **1.** Plain text passwords. You should be salting and hashing the password and passing that back to the DB **2.** SQL injection issues. You should be using parameters **3.** You should dispose your connection and command objects with `using`

Comment: It's Easy you need to pass values in Response.Redirect("~/Student Status.aspx?StudId=" + StudentId+ "); and get the value by using string StudentID= Request.QueryString["StudId"].ToString(); and get data by using Student ID.